# How to simplify complex category condition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have so many condition and I want to check value and find the category of that range. I tried it and it working correctly. I thought there is a simple way to do solve this kind of logic problem in kotlin. I want to be easy this kind of problem for testing purpose and many more.

```
class Abc {

    val list by lazy {
        mutableListOf(
            getFirstItem(),
            getSecondItem(),
            getThirdItem(),
            getFourthItem(),
            getFifthItem(),
            getSixthItem()
        )
    }

    private fun getFirstItem(): Item {
        return Item("Low") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne < 90 && itemTwo < 60)
        }
    }

    private fun getSecondItem(): Item {
        return Item("Normal") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne in 90..119 && itemTwo in 60..80)
        }
    }

    private fun getThirdItem(): Item {
        return Item("Elevated") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne in 120..129 && itemTwo < 80)
        }
    }

    private fun getFourthItem(): Item {
        return Item("High") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne in 130..139 || itemTwo in 80..89)
        }
    }

    private fun getFifthItem(): Item {
        return Item("Very high") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne in 140..179 || itemTwo in 90..119)
        }
    }

    private fun getSixthItem(): Item {
        return Item("Extremely High") { itemOne, itemTwo ->
            (itemOne >= 180 || itemTwo >= 120)
        }
    }

    fun getItem(itemOne: Int, itemTwo: Int): Item {
        for (item in list) {
            if (item.condition(itemOne, itemTwo)) {
                return item
            }
        }
        return Item("Hello") { valueOne, valueTwo ->
            (valueOne < 10 && valueTwo < 20)
        }
    }
}

data class Item(
    val itemName: String,
    val condition: (Int, Int) -> Boolean,
)
```

So I tried to search in stack overflow found `IntRange` suites better for some conditions but I am not 100% sure it works in all above conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data class Item(
  val itemName: String,
  val condition: (Int, Int) -> Boolean,
)

val list = listOf(
  Item("Low") { value1, value2 -> (value1 < 90 && value2 < 60) },
  Item("Normal") { value1, value2 -> (value1 in 90..119 && value2 in 60..80) },
  Item("Elevated") { value1, value2 -> (value1 in 120..129 && value2 < 80) },
  Item("High") { value1, value2 -> (value1 in 130..139 || value2 in 80..89) },
  Item("Very high") { value1, value2 -> (value1 in 140..179 || value2 in 90..119) },
  Item("Extremely High") { value1, value2 -> (value1 >= 180 || value2 >= 120) }
)

val result = list
  .filter { it.condition(95, 70) }
  .ifEmpty { Item("Hello") { value1, value2 -> (value1 < 10 && value2 < 20) } }
```

Comment: thanks for great solution. Is there a way be can simplify my `getFirstItem`....`getSixthItem` conditions?

Comment: @VivekModi if you can make `condition` take a `(Pair<Int, Int>) -> Boolean` instead, you can use `it.first` and `it.second` and omit the parameter names in your lamba, e.g. `Item("Low") { it.first < 90 && it.second < 60 }`